# Red transcriptional reporter in Psudomonas putida

Tags: microbiology, fluorescent-microscopy

I need to build a transcriptional reporter in *P. putida* with high excitation wavelength,in order to decrease phototoxicity (I have been using mNeonGreen until now,  and I would like to try something red).

My colleagues reported to me that previous tries with mCherry and mKate2 failed because:

- mCherry seems to have a very long maturation time, not suitable for
  my experiments
- mKate2 did not show any expression at all

Does anybody have experience with transcriptional reporters in *P. putida*?
Any ideas? (DsRed? re-try with mKate?)

I am measuring the expression of a PsrI (sigma factor for siderophore production) regulated gene.

Comment: What about RFP (red homologue to GFP)?